# IOS video playsinline not working in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have used playsinline with the webkit, it still does not seem to work- please have a look at the code and the video

Here is the link for the video demonstrating the problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/16jjVvLMpD64d-PYExxcNSshwbDjVGRsK/view?usp=sharing

```
<video 
    class="introvideo" 
    playsinline 
    webkit-playsinline
    autoPlay={true} 
    loop 
    
    preload={true}
    muted={true}> 
        <source 
            autoPlay={true} 
            muted={true} 
            loop 

            alt='starlatechdemovideo' 
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxx/video/upload/c_scale,w_800,q_auto/FinalPrct__cz7.mp4" 
            type='video/mp4' 
        />
</video>
```

Comment: I am uploading a video to showcase the problem...

Answer (score 4):

The problem was using playsinline instead of playsInline in ReactJS. Also, I added webkit-playsinline={true}.

Comment: can you add a complete example with the solution?